# Array in Struct, Pointers [C++ Beginner]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

Coming from a Java, PHP background, I am trying to get into C++. I would like to store an array in a struct. My problem is specifying the size of the array after initialising the struct.

Here's my code for the struct:

```
struct SpriteAnimation {
    // ...
    int parts;                  // total number of animation-parts
    unsigned int textures[];    // array to store all animation-parts
    // ...
};
```

And here for the main function:

```
SpriteAnimation bg_anim;
bg_anim.parts = 3; 
unsigned int *myarray = new unsigned int[bg_anim.parts];
bg_anim.textures = myarray;
```

What do I need to change to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

In modern C++, you would use a dynamic container for the inner "array":

```
struct SpriteAnimation {
  std::vector<unsigned int> textures;    // array to store all animation-parts
  size_t num_parts() const { return textures.size(); }
};
```

This is by far safer and more modular than anything you could try with manually allocated storage. Usage:

```
SpriteAnimation x;
x.textures.push_back(12);  // add an element
x.textures.push_back(18);  // add another element

SpriteAnimation y = x;     // make a copy

std::cout << "We have " << x.num_textures() << " textures." std::endl; // report
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain your objection? I understand that this isn't the "C array way" of doing things, but the question asks for a C++ solution, and the idiomatic and moral way to do C++ is to use (exception-safe and resource-managing and single-responsibility) containers as building blocks.

Comment: How does this know the size of the array (or `vector` - could you explain the difference, please)? Does `push_back()` resize it by creating a new one each time it is called? That would be horribly inefficient compared to John's solution, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Ben: Explaining the full workings of `vector` is beyond this comment, but do [read it up](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) -- yes, `push_back` does append a new element, but this is amortized O(1) thanks to magic. In fact, most of the C++ standard library can only be described as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct SpriteAnimation {
    // ...
    int parts;                  // total number of animation-parts
    unsigned int * textures;    // array to store all animation-parts
    // ...
};
```

You can use `type name[]` syntax only if you declare members inline.

Comment: Is it correct to then use it with `bg_anim.textures = new unsigned int[bg_anim.parts];` ?

Comment: What happens when you copy your struct? What happens when there's an exception?

Comment: @Ben yes that works correctly, in fact it wasn't correct before, as texture is a dynamically allocated array and should be shown as a pointer. You should lookup classes if you wish to use C++ as you are using c style syntax. Also remember to delete[] the array at the end

Answer (score 0):

Size of a struct must be known at a compilation time.

Comment: He was meaning to use a pointer and the type unsigned int * is a static size

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the issue through following code.It might be having design issues so please look it up the following code works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct lol {
  // ...
  int parts;                  // total number of animation-parts
  unsigned int *texture;   // array to store all animation-parts
  // ...
};

int main() {
  // your code goes here
  lol bg_anim;
  bg_anim.parts = 3; 
  unsigned int *myarray = new unsigned int[bg_anim.parts];
  bg_anim.texture = myarray;
  return 0;
 }
```

Forgive me for using `lol` instead of your specified name.Do tell me any issues.And help me if there are other issues in my code.
Thank you !! :)

Comment: by the way a `struct` is nothing but a class with everything public.A better solution would have been to use classes.